# Count words without vowels in a given list in c

Tags: arrays, c, count, cpu-word

I am trying to count the words that do not contain any vowel in a given list. Here's my code:

```
int noVowel(char * List[], int nSize){
int i, j, count = 0;

for(i=0; i<nSize; i++){
for(j=0; j<strlen(List[j]); j++){
        if(*List[j]!='a' || *List[j]!='e' || *List[j]!='i' || *List[j]!='o' || *List[j]!='u')
            count++;
    }
}
return count;}
```

List[] is the list of words I have to check.
nSize is the number of words listed in the List[].

I would like to ask for help in returning the **number of *words* without vowels**. I apologize for the confusing code as I am new to programming.

Comment: What is the problem you have with the code? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: As a ***guess*** about what problem you might have, I recommend you learn about [De Morgans's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), on how to negate or reverse conditions.

Comment: Also: you have two loops, but you never use the `i` index.

Comment: Oh yeah, you always check `List[j][0]`, when you should check `List[i][j]`.

Comment: try to avoid things like `for(j=0; j<strlen(str); j++)` because it usually results in O(N^2) complexity. `strlen()` must iterate over the whole string to find it's ending character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a correction of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isVowel(char c) {
    if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c =='u' || c =='y')
        return (1);
    else
        return (0);
}
```

First, here is a function that tells you if a character is a vowel by returning 1 (if it is not a vowel, it returns 0).

```
int noVowel(char *List[], int nSize){
    int i, j, count = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < nSize; i++) {
        
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(List[i]); j++) {

            if (isVowel(List[i][j]) == 1)
                break ;
        }
        if (List[i][j] == '\0')
                count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Secondly, like you, I did two loops to go through all the characters of my strings. If I find a vowel, I break, which means I go outside the current loop. If I am outside the second loop, I want to know if I have been able to go to the end of the string. If yes, I did not find any vowel, so I can increment my count int.

There was a mistake in your implementation of the 2 loops. By running this version displaying characters one by one you should see that there is an issue.

```
for(i=0; i<nSize; i++){
    for(j=0; j<strlen(List[j]); j++){
        printf("%c", List[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

P.S.: Indentation is important in programming it makes your code readable easily. At my school we use the following conventions https://cdn.intra.42.fr/pdf/pdf/960/norme.en.pdf (you should not apply all the rules they propose, but some of them are good practices)

Comment: I appreciate this! I'd like to ask, is there an alternative for break? Also, I am trying to solve this problem by using one function only (noVowel). Is there a way I could do this without the isVowel function?

Comment: Yes, ofr example instead of "break" you could use a variable that you would change if you find a vowel.This variable would help you determine if you should increase count. Sure you can take the content of the isVowel function and put it inside the if statement.

Comment: I was able to put the isVowel function inside the noVowel function, but I don't quite get using a variable instead of break. I initialized check = 0 and if there is a vowel, check = 1. I added check!=1 outside the loop together with List[i][j] == '\0' is this correct?

Comment: You are on the good path, if something is not working, try to debug it by displaying your variables and see if their values match what you expect them to be.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much! :))

Comment: regarding: `for(j = 0; j < strlen(List[i]); j++) {`  this is unnecessarily complex.  Since each string ends in a NUL byte, much better to use: `for( j = 0; List[i][j]; j++ ) {`